# document.parentWindow.frameElement is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to access the `frameElement` of `document.parentWindow` to get its form's ID. The code below works fine with IE10 but on IE11 it is saying `frameElement` is `null`.

```
callercontext = document.parentWindow.frameElement.parentElement.document.forms[0].id;
```

Can anyone suggest how to make it work on IE11?

Comment: You will have to show the relevant HTML hierarchy so we can see what exactly you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

A `.frameElement` property refers to an object like an `iframe` or a `frame` that contains the current content.  So, it appears that you're looking for a `.document` property on the parent object of a frame or iframe object.  `document` is a property of a `window`, not of a typical HTML element.

If you show the relevant HTML and explain what you're trying to access from what starting point, we can likely make a suggestion as to how to best do it.